# how to use close() in window.open()

Tags: javascript, dom

Hello i have a script like this, if alert OK open new window -> access the link -> and automatic close by timeout. the case is timeout cant read and the window still open, maybe someone can help.

```
function welcome(){
  let msg =confirm("Access Membership?");
  if (msg == true)
  {
    var win = window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank','');
    setTimeout(function () {
        win.close();
    }, 2000);
  }
}



async function asyncCall(){
  const phone = await getPhone();
  const alert  = await welcome();
}
```

Comment: there are several ways to get there.. anyway the most general one to me is using `bind()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#with_settimeout ... `setTimeout( (()=>{console.log(win)}).bind(this) , 2000);` - we are passing a closure to setTimeout as the callback and it's bound to the current `this` instead of the default `this`. So when the function will be executed, the variable `win` will still have the expected value. I would make an answer but the live snippets here are not friendly with `window.open`

Comment: *"the case is timeout cant read and the window still open"* That doesn't happen if I try it locally. The window opens, then closes two seconds later as expected. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. Provide full (but minimal!) code and markup that can be used to replicate the problem. (Sadly, Stack Snippets don't allow opening new windows, so we can't use them for this.)

Comment: Side note: There's no point in using `await` with `welcome`. It doesn't return a promise.

Comment: for the sake of records my approach seems to be valid only when using let instead of var... I focused on the wrong side of the issue. As someone else said you have a problem not clear reading your question